# How to change data attributes on drag and drop Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I made a jQuery function where the user can drag and drop divs. But I want to change their data attributes whenever users drag and drop them, eg-

```
<div data-num="1">one</div>
<div data-num="2">Two</div>
<div data-num="3">Three</div>
<div data-num="4">Four</div>
```

Whenever user drag div three and place it on the top then it should change its data attribute `data-num="3"` to `data-num="1"` and the div after it should change its data attribute to `data-num=2` and so on according to their position

What I am Trying

```
jQuery( "#app" ).sortable({ 
    update: function(a, b) { 
        parseInt(jQuery(a).attr("data-num"),10) - parseInt(jQuery(b).attr("data-num"),10);
    }          
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can hook an event handler to the `stop` event of the sortable. Then you can loop through each child `div` in `#app` and update the `data-num` to match the index of the element. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#app").sortable({
    stop: () => {
      $('#app > div').each((i, el) => $(el).data('num', i + 1));
    }
  });

  // only for testing...
  $('button').on('click', () => {
    $('#app > div').each((i, el) => console.log(`${el.textContent} - ${$(el).data('num')}`));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div data-num="1">One</div>
  <div data-num="2">Two</div>
  <div data-num="3">Three</div>
  <div data-num="4">Four</div>
</div>

<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it is changing values in the console but no changes in data attribute at all. https://jsfiddle.net/rpshagcf/

Comment: That's correct behaviour. jQuery changes the data attribute in memory only. So long as you always use `data()` to get/set the value (and never `attr()`) - which is the better practice, then the code will work fine

Answer (score 1):

we can also achieve this by using the item index

```
jQuery("#app").sortable({
   update: function(e, ui) {
       jQuery("#app div").each(function(i, elm) {
           $elm = jQuery(elm);
           var elindex = $elm.index("#app div");
           $elm.attr("data-num", elindex+1);
       });
    }   
});
```